# Import issue with Theano: AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'poll'

Tags: python, django, import, theano, keras

I've switched to a new machine and tried to use my code (that working on the previous one).
I'm using python/django/Theano/Keras with the following versions (aligned with the previous machine of course...):

- Django==1.9.6
- django-cors-headers==1.1.0
- django-user-agents==0.3.0
- Keras==1.0.3
- python-apt===0.9.3.5ubuntu2
- python-dateutil==2.5.3
- python-debian===0.1.21-nmu2ubuntu2
- scipy==0.17.1
- Theano==0.8.2

On one of the import I get the following error:
(Note that in other case I got the error of missing gof... but that might be a different issue)

- Last import fail line:

  ```
  AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'poll'
  ```

Any Ideas?
Thanks!

- Short version:

`File "/home/django/django_project/textlab/mainClasses/UploadNewSetCluster2TLChosen.py", line 10, in <module>
        from keras.models import model_from_json
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/keras/__init__.py", line 2, in <module>
        from . import backend
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/keras/backend/__init__.py", line 51, in <module>
        from .theano_backend import *
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/keras/backend/theano_backend.py", line 1, in <module>
        import theano
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/theano/__init__.py", line 42, in <module>
        from theano.configdefaults import config
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/theano/configdefaults.py", line 1452, in <module>
        p_out = output_subprocess_Popen([config.cxx, '-dumpversion'])
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/theano/misc/windows.py", line 78, in output_subprocess_Popen
        out = p.communicate()
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 799, in communicate
        return self._communicate(input)
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1401, in _communicate
        stdout, stderr = self._communicate_with_poll(input)
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1431, in _communicate_with_poll
        poller = select.poll()
    AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'poll'`

- Full Version
  `[05/Aug/2016 08:22:50] ERROR [/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py:284] Internal Server Error: /dashboardeventreport
  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 123, in get_response
      response = middleware_method(request)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/middleware/common.py", line 61, in process_request
      if self.should_redirect_with_slash(request):
    File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/middleware/common.py", line 79, in should_redirect_with_slash
      not urlresolvers.is_valid_path(request.path_info, urlconf)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py", line 668, in is_valid_path
      resolve(path, urlconf)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py", line 534, in resolve
      return get_resolver(urlconf).resolve(path)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py", line 374, in resolve
      for pattern in self.url_patterns:
    File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 33, in __get__
      res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py", line 417, in url_patterns
      patterns = getattr(self.urlconf_module, "urlpatterns", self.urlconf_module)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 33, in __get__
      res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py", line 410, in urlconf_module
      return import_module(self.urlconf_name)
    File "/usr/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
      __import__(name)
    File "/home/django/django_project/django_project/urls.py", line 17, in <module>
      from textlab import views
    File "/home/django/django_project/textlab/views.py", line 43, in <module>
      from mainClasses import UploadNewSetCluster2TLChosen
    File "/home/django/django_project/textlab/mainClasses/UploadNewSetCluster2TLChosen.py", line 10, in <module>
      from keras.models import model_from_json
    File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/keras/__init__.py", line 2, in <module>
      from . import backend
    File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/keras/backend/__init__.py", line 51, in <module>
      from .theano_backend import *
    File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/keras/backend/theano_backend.py", line 1, in <module>
      import theano
    File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/theano/__init__.py", line 42, in <module>
      from theano.configdefaults import config
    File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/theano/configdefaults.py", line 1452, in <module>
      p_out = output_subprocess_Popen([config.cxx, '-dumpversion'])
    File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/theano/misc/windows.py", line 78, in output_subprocess_Popen
      out = p.communicate()
    File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 799, in communicate
      return self._communicate(input)
    File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1401, in _communicate
      stdout, stderr = self._communicate_with_poll(input)
    File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1431, in _communicate_with_poll
      poller = select.poll()
  AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'poll'`

Comment: From the [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/select.html#select.poll), which you should always check before asking here: "`select.poll()`: (Not supported by all operating systems.)" Is your new machine on a different OS from your old one?

Comment: Exactly the same: Ubuntu 14.04.4 LTS

Comment: Make sure you didn't name anything a name that would hide a built-in module, like `select.py` or something, and try doing `import select` and inspecting `select.__file__` and `hasattr(select, 'poll')`.

Comment: Checked... couldn't find anything like that. And If it's due to naming collision, I don't understand how come it happens only on the new machine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved!
The issue was gunicorn version.
gunicorn wasn't listed using pip freeze - therefore I didn't if the versions are aligned.
Anyway - this line solves the issue:

```
sudo pip install gunicorn==19.4.5
```

Note that you'll might have some problems with permissions for .theano folder.
In this case just use:

```
sudo chown django:django <your django folder>
```

Thanks!